# Drag to draw more shapes

Tags: java, mouseevent, listener

So right now I have a program that draws a circle when I right click, and a square when I left click, and when I shift click it clears the screen.

• What I want to do is to be able to drag and make the mouse leave a trail of figures as I drag.  How do I do that? Here is my program.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;`

    public class SimpleStamper extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Simple Stamper");
        SimpleStamper content = new SimpleStamper();
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocation(120,70);
        window.setSize(400,300);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------

    public SimpleStamper() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {

        if ( evt.isShiftDown() ) {



            repaint();
            return;
        }

        int x = evt.getX();  
        int y = evt.getY();  

        Graphics g = getGraphics(); 

        if ( evt.isMetaDown() ) {

            g.setColor(Color.RED);  
            g.fillOval( x - 30, y - 30, 60, 60 );
            g.setColor(Color.RED); 
            g.drawOval( x - 30, y - 30, 60, 60 );
        }
        else {

            g.setColor(Color.PINK);   
            g.fillRect( x - 15, y - 15, 30, 30 );
            g.setColor(Color.PINK); 
            g.drawRect( x - 15, y - 15, 30, 30 );
        }

        g.dispose();  

    } 

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) { }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) { }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) { }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) { }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have painting code in your mouse handler? Painting should be done only in the paint() method. When clicking, save the location and then paint the shape at that location in paint().

Comment: @Baelynn I've added a full re-implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add a MouseMotionListener, same as a MouseListener.

```
public class SimpleStamper 
extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
        int x = evt.getX();  
        int y = evt.getY();
        //... create another shape and add it to the list of shapes
        // (see Adrian's comment)
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
    }
//...
}
```

To continue the same shape, you must store the "current" shape in a class variable, to be done in mousePressed.

Note that this produces nothing but a wide line tracking the mouse movement. If you want to have distinct shapes drawn, you have to keep track of the last x and y, and create another shape only if the distance is greater than some parameter DMIN.

Below is a full rewrite.

```
public class Drag 
extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame window = new JFrame("Simple Stamper");
  Drag content = new Drag();
  window.setContentPane(content);
  window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  window.setLocation(120,70);
  window.setSize(400,300);
  window.setVisible(true);
}

public Drag() {
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener( this );
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
private java.util.List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
  private enum Form {
    CIRCLE, SQUARE;
  }
  private Form lastForm;
  private int lastX;
  private int lastY;
  private static final int DMIN = 20;

  private void addShape( Form form, int x, int y, int a ){
    switch( form ){
    case CIRCLE:
      shapes.add( new Ellipse2D.Double( x-a/2.0, y-a/2.0, a, a ) );
      break;
    case SQUARE:
      shapes.add( new Rectangle2D.Double( x-a/2.0, y-a/2.0, a, a ) );
      break;
    }
    repaint();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    for( Shape s: shapes ){
      if( s instanceof Rectangle2D ){
        g2.setColor(Color.PINK);
      } else {
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);  
      }
      g2.fill( s );
      g2.draw( s );
    }
  }

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
    int x = evt.getX();  
    int y = evt.getY();
    int dx = lastX - x; 
    int dy = lastY - y; 
    if( dx*dx + dy*dy > DMIN*DMIN ){
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        addShape( lastForm, lastX, lastY, 60 );
    }
  }
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
  if ( evt.isShiftDown() ) {
    shapes.clear();
    repaint();
    return;
  }
  lastX = evt.getX();
  lastY = evt.getY();
  if ( evt.isMetaDown() ) {
     lastForm = Form.CIRCLE;
  } else {
     lastForm = Form.SQUARE;
  }
  addShape( lastForm, lastX, lastY, 60 );
} 

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) { }
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) { }
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) { }
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) { }
}
```